# Java modifying array class to descending order

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting

```
public static void selectionSort(int [] array) {

    int Scan, index, minIndex, minValue;

    for (Scan = 0; Scan < (array.length-1); Scan++) {

        minIndex = Scan;
        minValue = array[Scan];

        for(index = Scan + 1; index < (array.length); index++) {

            if (array[index] < minValue) {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }

        array[minIndex] = array[Scan];
        array[Scan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

I just need help putting this in descending order. Most of what i have tried have made this sorter class not function or just wouldnt run properly. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: `array[index] < minValue` -> `array[index] > minValue`

Comment: @4castle You could post that as an answer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't have time at the moment. Someone else can if they wish.

Comment: Thanks mates much appricated

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Sort array using `java.util.Arrays`

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(array);
```

**2.** Add sorted array to another array i.e. reverseSortedArray

```
int[] reverseSortedArray = new int[array.length];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
   reverseSortedArray[i] = array[array.length - (i + 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you wrote it's wrong It will be

```
if (array[index] < minValue)
```

like this way .